# Can i write the output format created by prettytable into a file?

Tags: python, python-3.x

`prettytable.PrettyTable` can represent tabular data in visually appealing formatted tables, and print these tables to the terminal.

How do I save a table as a text file?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

According to the [tutorial section on ASCII tables](https://code.google.com/p/prettytable/wiki/Tutorial#ASCII_tables), you can get the table output as a string:

```
table = ... # code for creating table goes here
table_txt = table.get_string()
with open('output.txt','w') as file:
    file.write(table_txt)
```